# Calling WorkFlow Soap Service from PCL

Tags: soap, workflow, xamarin, soap-client, portable-class-library

I have a WorkFlow Service hosted in a server: http://myServer.net/MyWorkflowService.xamlx

and it's working normally, I called it from a Windows Phone app before and working.

Now, I wanted to call it from a PCL Project (profile 78) for Xamarin.

I got this error:

> A correlation query yielded an empty result set. Please ensure
>   correlation queries for the endpoint are correctly configured.

I added it as a service reference, and I call an Async Method, and subscribes for completed event:

example

```
TaskCompletionSource<MyResponse> tsk = new TaskCompletionSource<MyResponse>();
            WorkFlowService.SubmitModel serviceModel = new WorkFlowService.SubmitModel()
            {
                List = MyList.ToArray<string>(),
                Guid = Guid,
                Description = Description,
                userid = UserId
            };
            WorkFlowClient.SubmitCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (eventArgs.Error != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception : DataService : Adding New" + eventArgs.Error.Message);
                    tsk.TrySetResult(new MyResponse() {
                        HasError = true
                    });
                }
            else
            {
                tsk.TrySetResult(new MyResponse()
                {
                    HasError = false
                });
            }
            };
            WorkFlowClient.SubmitAsync(new WorkFlowService.SubmitRequest((serviceModel)));
            return tsk.Task;
```

I should send an array of strings with my request, Should I provide ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file and what is the build action for it inside the PCL?!

Comment: Please show the code you are using to call the service.

Comment: I've added more info, Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest adding some server logging to determine what is different between the WP request and the iOS one.